# Error with "#include <cstdint>" using Clang++-17

Tags: c++, ubuntu, llvm

I installed llvm-17 using Automatic install script(https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh) into my Ubuntu machine.

Then, I tried to compile some c++ files, but Compile Failed.

```
main.cc:1:10: fatal error: 'cstdint' file not found
    1 | #include <cstdint>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

This is the error message.
How I solve this problem?

Comment: It says cstdint can't be found. Were you able to install all the headers and the standard C++ libraries?

Comment: Can you include `<stdint.h>`? If not then your installation might be incomplete. How did you install Clang? What C++ standard library have you installed?

Comment: I can include <stdint.h> but link error occurred./usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory

Comment: Looks like you installed the compiler but not the standard C++ library.

Comment: The library `stdc++` is the GCC implementation of the standard library, which Clang can use. Did you install the Clang-specific libc++? Then you need to use it with the option `-stdlib=libc++`. Otherwise you need to install the GCC C++ compiler `g++`.

Comment: Compile Successed by adding '-stdlib=libc++' option. Thank you for being so helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The llvm.sh bug was fixed when I attempted to reproduce, but I can provide some insights on the possible reason. As shared by Rurou2, the issue arises when `clang` fails to detect `gcc` and `libstdc++` correctly. To resolve this, you can add the `-stdlib=libc++` argument to utilize the embedded `libc++` in llvm as a workaround.

For those manually building llvm/clang, please take note of the tip mentioned in [clang's get_started page](https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html).

> If you intend to use Clang's C++ support, you may need to tell it how to find your C++ standard library headers.
> In general, Clang will detect the best version of libstdc++ headers available and use them - it will look both for system installations of libstdc++ as well as installations adjacent to Clang itself.
> If your configuration fits neither of these scenarios, you can use the -DGCC_INSTALL_PREFIX cmake option to tell Clang where the gcc containing the desired libstdc++ is installed.

To ensure `clang` can locate `gcc` correctly, you should **always** specify `GCC_INSTALL_PREFIX`. Otherwise, llvm will only search for `/` and `../` by default, which might not be sufficient at times.

Answer (score 0):

I meet same compile error on my Mac-Mini. My error is due to:

- Compile code with XCode bundled clang, in the first day
- Update macOS system and XCode command line tools in the second day
- Add some new code, (re)build with previous build output

To resolve my compile error: I delete previous build out dir